# Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012

Tags: windows

I need to install Microsoft Report viewer Run time for running some report from a desktop application. I also need to install the System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 package for this. Which one to  install 64 bit or 32 bit, Is this for OS or Application. What type of resource load will these packages add to the servers – CPU or memory intensive?

Answer (score 1):

It will be installed on the basis on of your O.S version.

MS-SQL Server Report viewer will utilize both CPU and memory of your server.
You can find the detailed description [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29065).